# Erro ao imprimir as variáveis de um objeto de uma classe em código

Tags: string, dart, interpolação-de-string

Ao executar o código acaba me retornando o seguinte:

```
Oi, meu nome é Instance of 'Pessoa'.nome, tenho Instance of 'Pessoa'.idade anos
e meu pseudônimo é Instance of 'Pessoa'.pseudonimo.
```

- O esperado era:

```
Oi, meu nome é Rodrigo, tenho 23 anos e meu pseudônimo é Kyukay.
```

- Código Dart

```
main() {
  var pessoa = new Pessoa();
  print("Oi, meu nome é $pessoa.nome, tenho $pessoa.idade e meu pseudônimo é $pessoa.pseudonimo.");
}

class Pessoa {
  String nome = "Rodrigo";
  String pseudonimo = "Kyukay";
  int idade = 23;  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use chaves para delimitar o que é código dentro da *string*. O ponto que ele encontra indica que terminou o código, então ele usa a variável do objeto para interpretar como código e o `.nome` vira texto. As chaves indica que é tudo uma coisa só, aí imprime certo porque pega a variável interna do objeto. Por consistência recomendo usar sempre, até quando não precisa.

```
import 'dart:io';
 
main() {
    var pessoa = Pessoa();
    print("Oi, meu nome é ${pessoa.nome}, tenho ${pessoa.idade} e meu pseudônimo é $pessoa.pseudonimo.");
}

class Pessoa {
    String nome = "Rodrigo";
    String pseudonimo = "Kyukay";
    int idade = 23;  
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/Nzxiiz). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ykhghzyp-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Dart/Interpolation.dt).

Comment: Entendi, o problema foi resolvido, obrigado.

Comment: @Kyukay dê uma olhada no [tour], você pode aceitar a resposta.